# How to install npm module bluetooth-serial-port with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: node.js, windows-7, visual-studio-2013, bluetooth

Tried to do npm install bluetooth-serial-port in Windows 7 with Python 3.7 and Visual Studio 2013. But got error on installation saying python version should be between 2.5.0 and 3.0. Uninstalled Python 3.7 and installed Python 2.7 solved that problem. Then it failed on finding WindowsSDKVer.

Answer (score 1):

Tried the following command to install npm module bluetooth-serial-port and installation is success.

npm install bluetooth-serial-port --msvs_version=2013